# how I can pass the variables from one function to another

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

How can I pass the variables from one function to another, so I create variable to create much of movieclips(mc)? mc has some attributes. Now after I created mc, I want to pass this mc with its attribute to another function, I will go to another function by addeventlistener to continue my code. I hope I explain good.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.xml.XMLNode;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class copy extends MovieClip {
        public var txml:XML;
        public var xmlloader:URLLoader= new URLLoader();
        public function copy() { 
            xmlloader.load(new URLRequest("‫‫olwantree.xml"));
            xmlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);
        }

        public var attributes:XMLList;
        public function loaded(e:Event):void {      
            txml = new XML(xmlloader.data);
            attributes = txml.descendants();
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < attributes.length(); i++) {
                var name:String = attributes[i].@name;
                var id:String = attributes[i].@id;
                var status:String = attributes[i].@status;
                var child:int = attributes[i].@child;
                addmc(name, id, status, child);

            }
       }     

       public function addmc(name, id,status, child):void {
           var mc:Array = new Array();
           var dead:Dead = new Dead();
           var baby:Baby = new Baby();
           var txtf:TextField = new TextField();
           var txtformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
           mc[id] = new MovieClip();
           mc[id].name = id;
           mc[id].child = child;
           mc[id].status = status;
           mc[id].graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
           mc[id].graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 101, 101);
           mc[id].graphics.endFill();

           if (id == "1") {
               mc[id].visible = true;
           } else {
               mc[id].visible = false;
           }
           // ; // wt?!

           addChild(mc[id]);
           mc[id].x = mc[id].y = 0;
           txtformat.align = "right";
           txtf.defaultTextFormat = txtformat;
           mc[id].addChild(txtf);
           txtf.text=name ;

           if (child == " ") {
           } else {
               mc[id].addChild(baby);
               mc[id].buttonMode = true;
           }

           if (status=="d") {
               mc[id].addChild(dead)}
               mc[id].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, traceme);
           }

           public function traceme(e:MouseEvent):void {
             //here is the wrong
           }
       }
  }
```

I display only the first node, within mc. When I click this signal mc I want to display another mc. I want to get the all variable from loaded and addmc functions to reuse it in traceme function.

Comment: This was one of the worst codes I've ever seen. If you want to use variables in two functions - just declare them as a member variable!

Comment: thank you  Andrey Popov, I am new in as3. now can you give me smale example about member variable?.

Comment: `public var txml:XML;` - it's defined in the class and not in any function, so it's "visible" for all functions. If you defined it **inside** a function, it will be visible only for this functions. Google for "variables scope"..